# Formula to Detect and Alter Numeric Value with Decimal

Tags: excel

I have a project, in which after a few multiplications, a number value might end with #.25 #.50 or #.75. I would like to know if there is a way that Excel can detect the .25 or .75, in which case I would like it to erase the .25 or change the .75 to .5.

Example: Value is `213.25` ; I would like the value to be changed to `213`.

Or: Value is `551.75` ; I would like the value to be changed to `551.5`.

Comment: What is the current formula in those cells?

Comment: =SI(SUMA(C12,E12,K12,M12,O12,G12)>45,(SUMA(O12,M12,K12,G12,E12,C12)-45)*1.5+45+SUMA(C15,E15,G15,K15,M15,O15)*1.5+SUMA(I12,I15)*1.5,SUMA(C12,E12,K12,M12,O12,G12)+SUMA(C15,E15,G15,K15,M15,O15)+SUMA(I12,I15))

Comment: Wrap that formula in: `=ROUNDDOWN(([your formulahere])*2,0)/2` -- sorry not sure what your localized version of `ROUNDDOWN` is

Comment: Why not just use [`=FLOOR(<Your Existing Formula>, .5)`](https://support.office.com/en-gb/article/floor-function-14bb497c-24f2-4e04-b327-b0b4de5a8886)?

Comment: Yeah, too many arguments for the function :( That's for @cybernetic.nomad im gonna try the Floor

Comment: Thanks!! It helped a lot!!